Difference in difference regression with multiple treatments & a binary outcome
I’m trying to assess the impact on a “Business A” when its customers interact with a competitor business for the first time. I’m using difference in difference regression to gauge this, and the outcome is binary where 12 months after interacting with a competitor, a customer has either attrited from Business A’s loyalty program (0) or is still a loyalty customer (1). In this case, “treatment” is defined as interacting with a competitor for the first time, and there are about 5 competitors I’ve choosen to assess, meaning that there are 5 treatments. Customers in my dataset often interact with more than one competitor in the treatment period, which is the same for all 5 competitors. What would be the best way to assess the casual effect / coefficients of each of these treatments? Currently, I’ve set up my inputs so that each treatment is given a DID interaction variable like so: Outcome = … (time * treatment1) + (time * treatment2) + …. etc etc. Is this fine? I can’t find a source supporting this set up. I’m planning to use LPM so that the coefficients are easily interpretable for a binary outcome.
